# Creating Mutiple records if Column1 value of Table A Not Exists In Column1 Value of Table B and So On

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, while-loop, ssis

I Have two table Table A and Table B which has hierarchical data, when compared at Column1 level two tables if Column1 of Table A Not exits in column1 of Table B, then create a record with only Column1 value of Table A, When Compared at Column1+Column2 level two tables if Column1+column2 of Table A does not exist in column1+column2 of Table B, then create two records, first records should have only column1 values from table A and second record should have column1 and column2 values and so on. Any ideas on how to achieve this using SQL or SSIS?

Table A

```
Division    State      County    City
-----------------------------------------
North       OH         ABCDE     CLE
South       TX         Dallas    Irving
East        NC         EFGH      Charlotte
```

Table B

```
Division   State      County     City
-----------------------------------------
North       OH         ABCDE      Akron
East        NC         PQRST      Duluth
South       LA         GHJKL      Boca
```

Expected Result:

```
Division   State     County  City
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
North      Null       Null    Null -- City(L4) got changed created this record at L1
North      OH         Null    Null -- City(L4) got changed created this record at L2 
North      OH         ABCDE   Null -- City(L4) got changed created this record at L3
East       Null       Null    Null -- City(L4) got changed created this record at L1
East       NC         Null    Null -- City(L4) got changed created this record at L2 
East       NC         EFGH    Null -- City(L4) got changed created this record at L3
East       Null       Null    Null -- County(L3) changed created L1 record
East       NC         Null    Null -- County(L3) changed Created L2 record
South      Null       Null    Null -- State (L2) Changed Created L1 record
```

Comment: What do you mean by Create record ? Edit the question add sample data & desired result.

Comment: when i mean create, Insert a record into a table.

Comment: Hi @Shaik! Welcome to Stack Overflow! In your expected results, are you wanting the Cities all set to null? Or are the expected results just the new records added?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you'd be after...

```
/* Setup, using table variables for this example */
declare @TableA table (Division varchar(50), [State] varchar(50), County varchar(50), City varchar(50))
declare @TableB table (Division varchar(50), [State] varchar(50), County varchar(50), City varchar(50))

insert into @TableA values   ('North','OH','ABCDE','CLE')
                            ,('South','TX','Dallas','Irving')
                            ,('East','NC','EFGH','Charlotte')

insert into @TableB values   ('North','OH','ABCDE','Akron')
                            ,('East','NC','PQRST','Duluth')
                            ,('South','LA','GHJKL','Boca')

--review initital tables
select * from @TableA
select * from @TableB

-- Top Level of Hierarchy...
insert into @TableB
select distinct
     A.Division
    ,NULL as [State]
    ,NULL as [County]
    ,NULL as [City]
from
    @TableA A
    left join
    @TableB B on A.Division = B.Division
             and B.[State] is null
             and B.County is null
             and B.City is null
where
    B.Division is null

-- 2nd Level of Hierarchy...
insert into @TableB
select distinct
     A.Division
    ,A.[State] as [State]
    ,NULL as [County]
    ,NULL as [City]
from
    @TableA A
    left join
    @TableB B on A.Division = B.Division
             and A.[State] = B.[State]
             and B.County is null
             and B.City is null
where
    B.Division is null
    and B.[State] is null

-- 3rd Level of Hierarchy...
insert into @TableB
select distinct
     A.Division
    ,A.[State] as [State]
    ,A.County as [County]
    ,NULL as [City]
from
    @TableA A
    left join
    @TableB B on A.Division = B.Division
             and A.[State] = B.[State]
             and A.County = B.County
             and B.City is null
where
    B.Division is null
    and B.[State] is null
    and B.County is null


-- Review results
select
    *
from
    @TableB
order by
    Division
    ,[State]
    ,County
    ,City
```

**Results**:

```
Division    State   County  City
---------------------------------------------
East        NULL    NULL    NULL
East        NC      NULL    NULL
East        NC      EFGH    NULL
East        NC      PQRST   Duluth
North       NULL    NULL    NULL
North       OH      NULL    NULL
North       OH      ABCDE   NULL
North       OH      ABCDE   Akron
South       NULL    NULL    NULL
South       LA      GHJKL   Boca
South       TX      NULL    NULL
South       TX      Dallas  NULL
```

Comment: Great approach. Can you please explain why are you inserting into table b?

Comment: Maybe I misread your question, but it seemed like that was your intention. If you prefer to populate a third table, you could alter the insert into table b for table c (or whatever it's called).